# Multiprocessing changed in python 3.9 from 3.7 on MacOSx, how to fix?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.9

Python 3.9 multiprocessing seems to run many extra loops over the whole file, while 3.7 didnt do this. The machine has 8 cores thus 8 loops. How do I fix this. This is not what I am expecting -- was the threading module also reworked, does this problem happen in that module also.   This is the code:

```
 !/usr/bin/python
from   time            import strftime
import multiprocessing as mp

print (strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ' Run line5 ' )

def pullLast():  
    print(12345678998765432345678)
    return 1

def mprocULwork(uplist): # build a queue with tuple
    ULsyms = [e for e in uplist if e is not None] 
    p_size          = mp.cpu_count()
    pool            = mp.Pool(processes=p_size, maxtasksperchild=400,)
    pool_outputs    = pool.map(ULProcess, ULsyms)
    pool.close()    # no more tasks
    pool.join()     # wrap up current tasks
    del pool
    print (strftime("%H:%M:%S"), "Finished ULwork")

def ULProcess(symbol):
    pSet    = 0
    print(pSet,symbol)
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    pSet    = 1
    symlist = ["G","Y","S" ]
    ullist  = symlist

    global lastPriceDF
    lastPriceDF  = pullLast()

    mprocULwork(ullist)                ####### <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<main entry
    print (strftime("%H:%M:%S"), "post")
   
print (strftime("%H:%M:%S"),  'Exiting....line last' )
```

This the output from python 3.7:

```
10:08:58 Run line5 
12345678998765432345678
0 G
0 Y
0 S
10:08:58 Finished ULwork
10:08:58 post
10:08:58 Exiting....line last
```

This is the output from 3.9:

```
10:20:44 Run line5 
12345678998765432345678
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
0 G
0 Y
0 S
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
10:20:44 Run line5 
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
10:20:44 Finished ULwork
10:20:44 post
10:20:44 Exiting....line last
```

Comment: Multiprocessing definitely can import your module from a child process, but you shouldn't be writing your software to do expensive work on import. This wasn't good practice in 3.7 either. If that _is_ the problem, though, then there'll be code that does work outside the `__name__ == "__main__"` guard (though what it looks like is that you're just doing _logging_ outside that guard, and assuming that if there's a log line there's work being duplicated).

Comment: Notice how you're doing some logging outside the guards? If `__name__` is not `__main__`, then we can be imported to do only a subset of the work, _not_ rerunning the whole file; you want to be sure to distinguish the cases in your logging, and not assume that the code is being rerun when all that's _really_ happening is just an import.

Comment: The OS; MacOSx checked on Linux

Comment: If you move the log lines into the guard, do you still see this problem? Because just importing the module is _supposed_ to be cheap enough to be something that can be done in each subprocess; if it's not that inexpensive, you're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: Move which line?

Comment: Move the lines `print (strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ' Run line5 ' )` and `print (strftime("%H:%M:%S"),  'Exiting....line last' )` -- those are the two lines you're leaving outside the guard, in the code that's supposed to be cheap enough for multiprocessing to rerun in each subprocess if it wants to.

Comment: anything you only want to execute in the main process, and not in the child on import..

Comment: removing those two lines did stop the print output, does not mean the that the looping isnt showing up as the print statements would show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Psychic debugging: You're on macOS. In 3.8, the `multiprocessing` module [switched from using the `'fork'` start method by default to the `'spawn'` start method](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#multiprocessing), because [the high-level macOS system libraries are not fork-safe and can cause crashes](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77906). Part of how the `'spawn'` method simulates forking is by reimporting the `__main__` module (but with a different `__name__` so a properly guarded module won't redo anything that's guarded).

If you want to roll the dice, go ahead and explicitly opt-in to the `'fork'` start method with [`multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method). More properly, fix your code to make it follow [the `multiprocessing` guidelines for the `'spawn'` (and `'forkserver'`) method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods).

Comment: The dev is on MacOS, deploy on Linux.

Comment: @Merlin: Okay, and your observed behavior was where? macOS or Linux? Linux should not have changed (it remains `'fork'` by default, unless some of your code is changing the default), but macOS definitely did.

Comment: in dev -- preprod. MacOS

Comment: @Merlin: Yep, that's the explanation then. The behavior you're seeing is what you'd expect for Windows (any Python version) and Python 3.8+ on macOS, the behavior you're used to is what you'd see on Linux (any Python version) and Python 3.7 and below on macOS.

Comment: @Merlin the direction of the python development has been towards spawn for a while now, as it helps to solve many longstanding issues with "fork"ing multi-threaded processes (often threads are used in libraries without it being explicitly clear to the user). Spawn provides a consistent experience across all OS's including windows which doesn't include "fork" at all. The default on linux remains "fork" because many rely on it for legacy reasons, so in this case it would be appropriate to manually set the start method to make sure dev and deploy behave the same.

Comment: The `mp.set_start_method('fork')` stop the loops -- but what is going on?   Does this apply to threading module also?

Comment: @Merlin: It's `multiprocessing`-specific, threads don't need it (and wouldn't benefit from it). It's not *loops*, per the end of my first paragraph, it's that each of the worker processes is initializing their fresh process by importing the `__main__` module (but with `__name__` not reporting itself as `'__main__'` so stuff protected by import guards isn't re-executed). If they didn't do that, the fresh process wouldn't know about *anything* except what you'd passed to `pool.map` directly (if the function called relied on something you imported, or a global you defined, it wouldn't exist).

Comment: And note, the function itself couldn't be found (functions are pickled by their qualified names, and it wouldn't be found unpicking). I'd recommend you make your code `'spawn'`-safe, following *all* of [the `multiprocessing` programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines); even if you use Linux with `'fork'` in production, there's no guarantee the default won't eventually change for Linux, and using `'fork'` in macOS is inherently unsafe (that's why they changed it). Writing safe `multiprocessing` code protects you against future problems.